# How to Customize "WordPress > Error" Text in Titlebar?

Tags: title

When a user doesn't enter all required things in comment box area and click on submit comment button, a new page is shown telling user that some required fields are missing such as name, email, etc.

The page contains `"WordPress > Error"` text in titlebar.

I want to replace this text with my custom text.

I have been doing this by manually replacing following line in `wp-includes\functions.php` file:

```
$title = $have_gettext ? __('WordPress › Error') : 'WordPress › Error';
```

Now I don’t want to edit core file. I want to know if it is possible to do the same thing by using my blog theme's `functions.php` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing interface string is often done using `gettext` translation filter, but I was in the mood for something different so creatively mangled die handler to achieve it:

```
add_filter( 'wp_die_handler', function () {

    if ( false !== strpos( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 'wp-comments-post.php' ) ) {
        return function ( $message, $title, $args ) {
            _default_wp_die_handler( $message, 'Our Custom Title', $args );
        };
    }

    return '_default_wp_die_handler';
} );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Please tell me one thing! Does your code only replace titlebar text of the error screen which is shown when user doesnt enter all required things in comment box or does it change the titlebar text in other screens as well?

Comment: This changes title on all error screens related to comment submission. You might further narrow condition down, since it probably does have access to submitted comment around there.

Comment: How do you apply this on all Errors shown? Like if I try to access the settings dashboard where I am not allowed or a post type I dont have access to? Everyone shows Wordpress > Error in the title. Can I change them all universally?